# read files/website as if it's STDIN to not write code twice

Tags: python, stdin

For [hackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/journey-to-the-moon) I often find myself writing code that takes input as STDIN but then I'd like to test it for large inputs as taking input from a file/site.  Ideally, I wouldn't have to write new code when reading from a file instead of reading from STDIN.

I.e., One example of file input is [here](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/784/input13.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1481404765&Signature=kfuy5d36%2B0HfDGiDQCFaia5wRkk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain):

but hackerRank takes the input as STDIN:

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
N, l = map(int, raw_input().split())
# N, l = 100000, 2

pairs = []

for i in xrange(l):
    a, b = map(int, raw_input().split())
    # Store a and b in an appropriate data structure
    pairs.append((a, b))
# pairs = [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Is there a general way to make sure when reading from a file it's also compatible with the reading from STDIN code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely good to reuse code.

Here's one approach. You can create an object that "acts like" raw_input, but when called,
it reads from a file instead of prompting.

```
def go(fn_get_input):
    N, l = map(int, fn_get_input().split())
    # N, l = 100000, 2
    pairs = []
    for i in xrange(l):
        a, b = map(int, fn_get_input().split())
        # Store a and b in an appropriate data structure
        pairs.append((a, b))
    # pairs = [(1,2), (3,4)]

class GetInputFromFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        self.lines = list(f)
        self.index = 0
        f.close()

    def __call__(self):
        ret = self.lines[self.index]
        ret = ret.rstrip() # remove the trailing newline
        self.index += 1
        return ret

# with raw input:
go(raw_input)
# with a file
go(GetInputFromFile('/path/to/file.txt'))
```

It will be nice to have this for writing tests, too.

This same pattern can be used to read from a website with urllib2. Note that in this code sample if you call the object more times than there are lines in the file, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the `fileinput` module. From https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fileinput.html :

> The typical use is:
>
> ```
> import fileinput
> for line in fileinput.input():
>     process(line)
> ```
>
> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. If a filename is '-', it is also replaced by sys.stdin.